# Verification of proof on commutativity of products

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $I$ and $J$ be two sets and let $f:I\times J \rightarrow G$ be a mapping into a commutative monoid. Prove that:
>
> $$\prod_{i\in I} \left(\prod_{j\in J} f(i, j)\right)
>  = \prod_{j\in J} \left(\prod_{i\in I} f(i, j)\right)$$

**My attempt is as follows:**

$$
\begin{split}
p &= \prod_{i\in I} \left(\prod_{j\in J} f(i, j)\right) \\
 &= \prod_{i\in I} \left(f(i, j_{0})...f(i, j_{n})\right) \\
 &= \left(f(i_{0}, j_{0})...f(i_{0}, j_{n}))\dots(f(i_{m}, j_{0})\dots f(i_{m}, j_{n})\right)\\
&\text{remove parenthesis (associativity) and rearrange the terms (commutativity)}\\
&= (f(i_{0}, j_{0})\dots f(i_{m}, j_{0}))\dots(f(i_{0}, j_{n})\dots f(i_{m}, j_{n})) \\
&= \prod_{j\in J} \left(f(i_{0}, j)\dots f(i_{m}, j)\right) \\
&= \prod_{j\in J} \left(\prod_{i\in I} f(i, j)\right).
\end{split}
$$

Is this valid? If not, how to prove the theorem?

Comment: Presumably $I$ and $J$ are finite (which you assume in your solution). For the most part the solution looks good, although you can be more rigorous in the 'rearrange the terms' part using induction, which might be expected for proofs at this level.